# Natural deduction in logic

Tags: logic

1. (∀x) (Lx → ¬Kx)
2. (∃z) (Rz ∧ Kz)
3. (∀y) [(¬Ly ∧ Ry)→By]
4. ⊢ (∃x) (Bx)

(1) I believe i could answer this first applying Universal and existential instantiation on numbers 1-3, then commutation and simplification in number 2 to get Kz then I'll apply Double negation to Kz and use it to get ¬Lx in number one using Modus Ponens. I'll also simplify number 2 to get Rz and add it to ¬Lx to get By using modus pones. 
(2) what i don't know is how will i address those quantifiers with different variables? Is it like the usual or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since (1)$\iff \forall x (K x\to \neg L x)$ we have [(1)$\land$(2)]$\to$$\exists z (R z \land K z \land \neg Lz)$$\to \exists z ((\neg L z)\land R z)$ , which, when applied to (3), implies $\exists z (B z).$ Any formal details that I have omitted, I think you can fill in.